# How can I search for documents that contain three times a special word?

Tags: solr, lucene

Solr should return the documents, that contain a given word minimum three times.
What is the query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr query search for multiple instances for single keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746538/solr-query-search-for-multiple-instances-for-single-keyword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use solr function query (**termfreq**) to get the term frequency of a term in a field in a particular document.

Documentation: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#termfreq

Sample Query:

```
fq={!frange l=3}termfreq(text,"special")
```

Complete Url:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q=*:*&fq={!frange l=3}termfreq(text,"special")
```

Comment: Do you know a way to use wildcards in the `termfreq` fq? so you could use `termfreq(text, manage*)` to match "Manager", "Manage" and "Management"?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to have a wildcard query with termfreq function. However if your field uses a stemmer (e.g. SnowballPorterFilterFactory), then all terms like (manager, manage, management, manages, managing, managed) will all map to the same stemmed token. (in this case manag)